# Twitter bootstrap table messed up?

Tags: html, dom, twitter-bootstrap

I was fiddling around with Bootstrap but came to a grinding halt with this error of it all being misplaced.

The source code generated was

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Anjul Photo Copy</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
      </style>

      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/textrace.js"></script>
            </head>
    <body> 
      <div class="page-header">
        <center><h1>Header <small>Header 2!</small></h1></center>
      </div>
      <span class="span2">
        <div class="well">
      <ul class="nav nav-list">  
        <li ><a tabindex="-1" href="/">Home</a></li>     
        <li ><a tabindex="-1" href="contact.php">Contact us</a></li>
        <li ><a tabindex="-1" href="services.php">Services</a></li>
        <li class='active'><a tabindex="-1" href="dba.php">AayuFill</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
       </ul></div>
 </span>



<span class="span8">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Fathers Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>aayush<td><td>agrawal<td><td>Ranjan Agrawal<td><td>4 oriental<td><tr>   </tbody>
    </table>
</span>     
        <div style="clear:both;"><center>Copyright &#169; Anjul Photo Copy</center></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

but as you can probably see, the table is gravely misplaced. Any advice on fixing it is HIGHLY appreciated.

[image]

Comment: So what's wrong with the table? It doesn't look misplaced.

Comment: Uh i am guessing the problem is centered at me. I will post a screenshot of what i see. On my screen the Table data races ahead of the th to make some big mash. And yes i am confident that i downloaded and linked correctly, i just reinstalled it actually.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/cFGCTJK.png

Comment: Got it. I added to your question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your table row structure :

```
<tr>
  <td>aayush<td>
  <td>agrawal<td>
  <td>Ranjan Agrawal<td>
  <td>4 oriental<td>
<tr>
```

You're not closing the `<td>` correctly. It should be :

```
<tr>
  <td>aayush</td>
  <td>agrawal</td>
  <td>Ranjan Agrawal</td>
  <td>4 oriental</td>
<tr>
```

You need to use `</td>` to close a `<td>`

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/zEJjK/) ... [W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) is your fiend

Comment: Thanks, i cant believe i missed that. Will mark when the timer is up.